# Adobe air-importing view class issue

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

```
package
{
    import spark.components.Label;
    import spark.components.TextArea;
    import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;
    import spark.components.View;

    public class UIHelper extends View
    {               
        private static var _instance:UIHelper = new UIHelper();

        private var _logText:TextArea;
        private var _convLabel:Label;
        private var _farVideoCarrier:SpriteVisualElement;
        private var _myVideoCarrier:SpriteVisualElement;

        public function UIHelper()
        {
            if(_instance !=null)
            {
                throw new Error("Singleton can only be accessed through Db.Instance");                  
            }
            logText = new TextArea;
            farVideoCarrier = new SpriteVisualElement;
            farVideoCarrier.width=300;
            farVideoCarrier.height=300;
            myVideoCarrier = new SpriteVisualElement;
            convLabel = new Label;
        }

        public function get convLabel():Label
        {
            return _convLabel;
        }

        public function set convLabel(value:Label):void
        {
            _convLabel = value;
        }

        public function get myVideoCarrier():SpriteVisualElement
        {
            return _myVideoCarrier;
        }

        public function set myVideoCarrier(value:SpriteVisualElement):void
        {
            _myVideoCarrier = value;
        }

        public function get farVideoCarrier():SpriteVisualElement
        {
            return _farVideoCarrier;
        }

        public function set farVideoCarrier(value:SpriteVisualElement):void
        {
            _farVideoCarrier = value;
        }

        public function get logText():TextArea
        {
            return _logText;
        }

        public function set logText(value:TextArea):void
        {
            _logText = value;
        }

        public static function get Instance():UIHelper
        {           
            return _instance;
        }
        //---------------------------------END---------------------------------
    }
}
```

This  is my UI class and I need to import view class here.  It keeps giving me error of "could not resolve view as a component implementation".

Answer (score 0):

Check that the correct SWC's are loaded inside your project